# How to redirect to a previous URL in Laravel 5.6 and intended

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel application I have a middleware for specific routes, in this middleware I validate to redirect to a url.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $isValidated= ....
    if ($isValidated) {
        session()->put('url.intended', URL::full());
        return redirect()->route('routeone')
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

in the store method of that table when you register I do a redirect in the following way, but it turns out that when I do it, it redirects me to `domain/img/favicon.png` and I did not do the previous route

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ....
    return redirect()->intended(session('url.intended') ?? '/admin');
}
```

What is the problem here or how could I address this detail to redirect to the url before the middleware redirects. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code :

```
$referrer = $this->request->headers->get('referer');

$url = $referrer ? $this->to($referrer) : $this->getPreviousUrlFromSession();
```

or directly :

```
$url = request()->headers->get('referer');
```

and

```
session()->put('url.intended', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do this

```
return back();
```

From the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#creating-redirects

Comment: No, you should read what this function does and you will realize that it is not enough